# how to convert M1 password hash to M2 password hash

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1, password

how to convert Magento 1 password hash to Magento 2 password hash?

for example:

M1 password hash of qwer@123 (password)

```
547e98d8739f52b1ac5759d6b0ec6813:q9n6S6pewXbHANHML6TRujGOigDA5CSo
```

M2 password hash of qwer@123 (password)

```
b3ef5674b8ae2a4ce0cefb10671fb5b2546475b020548275cad2ea070f2d435c:pQJccCQInyMFaDzVyqCbYCGE56o6avDo:1
```

I need to convert

```
547e98d8739f52b1ac5759d6b0ec6813:q9n6S6pewXbHANHML6TRujGOigDA5CSo -> b3ef5674b8ae2a4ce0cefb10671fb5b2546475b020548275cad2ea070f2d435c:pQJccCQInyMFaDzVyqCbYCGE56o6avDo:1
```

any help would be much apreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**My Try**

I got reference from data-migration-tool `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Customer/Helper.php` for changing M1 password hash to M2 password hash. I applied the same logic in my controller for testing purpose.

Custom controller:

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_account;
        /**#@+
     * Exploded password hash keys
     */
    const PASSWORD_HASH = 0;
    const PASSWORD_SALT = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $account

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_account=$account;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //password hash from M1
        $recordAttributesData['password_hash']="b1999e4f386208d438134f3ad3d5ab21:MGPHnykFc2IJ9mxQ8tZ6vNwEghzXcezv";
        //print M2 password hash
        echo $this->upgradeCustomerHash($recordAttributesData);
    }

    /**
     * Upgrade customer hash according M2 algorithm versions
     *
     * @param array $recordAttributesData
     * @return array
     */
    private function upgradeCustomerHash($recordAttributesData)
    {
        if (isset($recordAttributesData['password_hash'])) {
            $hash = $this->explodePasswordHash($recordAttributesData['password_hash']);

            if (strlen($hash[self::PASSWORD_HASH]) == 32) {
                $recordAttributesData['password_hash'] = implode(
                    ':',
                    [$hash[self::PASSWORD_HASH], $hash[self::PASSWORD_SALT], '0']
                );
            } elseif (strlen($hash[self::PASSWORD_HASH]) == 64) {
                $recordAttributesData['password_hash'] = implode(
                    ':',
                    [$hash[self::PASSWORD_HASH], $hash[self::PASSWORD_SALT], '1']
                );
            }
        }

        return $recordAttributesData['password_hash'];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $passwordHash
     * @return array
     */
    private function explodePasswordHash($passwordHash)
    {
        $explodedPassword = explode(':', $passwordHash, 2);
        $explodedPassword[self::PASSWORD_SALT] = isset($explodedPassword[self::PASSWORD_SALT])
            ? $explodedPassword[self::PASSWORD_SALT]
            : ''
        ;
        return $explodedPassword;
    }
}
```

it print the password hash `b1999e4f386208d438134f3ad3d5ab21:MGPHnykFc2IJ9mxQ8tZ6vNwEghzXcezv:0` after that I have updated the M2 Database, when I try to login, It allows. But after login it automatically update the password hash as `34bbb0468f2881c9f60964b66990bf26d9fb34d433b4df86bdb221148d775f5f:Oxrrm8cgdRf38fM5JzbPrI2E0VuFgZbp:1` in database, I have no issues in login.

I'm curious to know what is happening here? and which code part is responsible for this? if anyone know, please post your answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/175524/36463)

Comment: Hello @Bilal, is there is any way that Magento 2 can also support SHA1 password.Please refer my question and help me.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/238127/24878

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the exact same issues as you but I managed to fix my customer passwords by using this - https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/294312/46258

P.S. You will need to clear out generated/ and rebuild. I'm using:

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/composer_home/* var/generation/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* generated/code/* generated/metadata/*
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
php bin/magento cache:clean
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
```