# Upgrade customer hash according M2 algorithm versions - What is happening here?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento2-migration-tool, password

I got reference from data-migration-tool `vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/src/Migration/Step/Customer/Helper.php` for changing M1 password hash to M2 password hash. I applied the same logic in my controller for testing purpose.

Custom controller:

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Helloworld\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_account;
        /**#@+
     * Exploded password hash keys
     */
    const PASSWORD_HASH = 0;
    const PASSWORD_SALT = 1;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement $account

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_account=$account;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        //password hash from M1
        $recordAttributesData['password_hash']="b1999e4f386208d438134f3ad3d5ab21:MGPHnykFc2IJ9mxQ8tZ6vNwEghzXcezv";
        //print M2 password hash
        echo $this->upgradeCustomerHash($recordAttributesData);
    }

    /**
     * Upgrade customer hash according M2 algorithm versions
     *
     * @param array $recordAttributesData
     * @return array
     */
    private function upgradeCustomerHash($recordAttributesData)
    {
        if (isset($recordAttributesData['password_hash'])) {
            $hash = $this->explodePasswordHash($recordAttributesData['password_hash']);

            if (strlen($hash[self::PASSWORD_HASH]) == 32) {
                $recordAttributesData['password_hash'] = implode(
                    ':',
                    [$hash[self::PASSWORD_HASH], $hash[self::PASSWORD_SALT], '0']
                );
            } elseif (strlen($hash[self::PASSWORD_HASH]) == 64) {
                $recordAttributesData['password_hash'] = implode(
                    ':',
                    [$hash[self::PASSWORD_HASH], $hash[self::PASSWORD_SALT], '1']
                );
            }
        }

        return $recordAttributesData['password_hash'];
    }

    /**
     * @param string $passwordHash
     * @return array
     */
    private function explodePasswordHash($passwordHash)
    {
        $explodedPassword = explode(':', $passwordHash, 2);
        $explodedPassword[self::PASSWORD_SALT] = isset($explodedPassword[self::PASSWORD_SALT])
            ? $explodedPassword[self::PASSWORD_SALT]
            : ''
        ;
        return $explodedPassword;
    }
}
```

it print the password hash `b1999e4f386208d438134f3ad3d5ab21:MGPHnykFc2IJ9mxQ8tZ6vNwEghzXcezv:0` after that I have updated the M2 Database, when I try to login, It allows. But after login it automatically update the password hash as `34bbb0468f2881c9f60964b66990bf26d9fb34d433b4df86bdb221148d775f5f:Oxrrm8cgdRf38fM5JzbPrI2E0VuFgZbp:1` in database, I have no issues in login, I'm curious to know what is happening here?

which code part is responsible for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think magento2 updates the password field with the default hash algorithm sha256, maybe [here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/931) you could find some hints to find the responsible.